# node.js module: why files array is null

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been learning node.js and I have such example:

lesson6_module.js

```
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports = function (dir, regexFilter, callback) {
  fs.readdir(dir, function(err, files) {
    console.log('files.length ' + files.length);
    if (!err) {
      return callback(err, null);
    }
    var filteredFiles = [];
    files.forEach(function(file) {
      if (regexFilter.test(file)) {
        filteredFiles.push(file);
      }
    });
    console.log('filteredFiles.length ' + filteredFiles.length);
    callback(null, filteredFiles);
  });
};
```

lesson6.js

```
var lm6 = require('./lesson6_module.js');

var dir = process.argv[2];
var regex = new RegExp('\\.' + process.argv[3] + '$');
lm6(dir, regex, function(err, files) {
  files.forEach(function(file) {
    console.log(file);
  });
});
```

When I run it I get the error like this:

```
D:\devhome\nodejs\learn>node lesson6.js testdir txt
files.length 2

D:\devhome\nodejs\learn\lesson6.js:6
  files.forEach(function(file) {
        ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'forEach' of null
    at D:\devhome\nodejs\learn\lesson6.js:6:9
    at D:\devhome\nodejs\learn\lesson6_module.js:7:14
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Check the `err` parameter in your callback. `fs.readDir()` seems to return an error in the first place.

Comment: It is `if (!err) {` but should be `if (err) {`. Now it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simple bug (thanks to @Sirko comments I catched it faster):

```
if (!err) {
  return callback(err, null);
}
```

Should be:

```
if (err) {
  return callback(err, null);
}
```